# ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() error?

Tags: django, faker

I am running a populating script which I learned through a tutorial, but I do not know why am I getting this error.

I'm a novice so any help would be really appreciated!

```
from faker import Faker
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic
import random
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

django.setup()


fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['search', 'social', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t
    enter code here

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top = add_topic()
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(top_name=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg, date=fake_date)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('populating script')
    populate(20)
    print('poulated')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is happening because you are trying to import your models before you configure Django. Move the line `from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic` below the line where you call `django.setup()`

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I had to disable autopep8 which was making this a mess and it worked

Comment: You could configure `autopep8` to ignore the `E402` error to prevent it moving the imports, e.g. `autopep8 --ignore E402`.